# Ошибка команды mongodump

Tags: база-данных, mongodb

Нужно склонить базу данных
сама команда указана в инструкции

```
mongodump -d db_name -h **.***.***.** -u user -p password -o ./db_name_dump
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Что это может быть?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195997/mongodb-failed-error-connecting-to-db-server-no-reachable-servers ?

Comment: Спасибо) Уже разобрался